# iOS coreData Repeating the data and adding something that i did not stored

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

i am a beginner iOS developer, developing in swift, while working on coreData i am having some problem which is [Shown in Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYkfq.png) that is the data repeating it self at every new startup and the first data with RS.0.0 i do not know from where it is coming and does it have to do something with repeating data. 
here is the func that I am using to fetch data.

`

```
func doFetch(){

        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Items> = Items.fetchRequest()
        let dateSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "created", ascending: false)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [dateSort]

        let FRC = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context , sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        self.FRC = FRC

        do {
            try FRC.performFetch()
        } catch  {
            let error = error as NSError
            print("\(error)")
        }

    }
```

and here is the other function i am using..

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?)
    {
        switch (type)
        {

        case.insert:
            if let indexpath = newIndexPath {

                tableVieww.insertRows(at: [indexpath], with: .fade)
            }
            break

        case.delete:
            if let indexpath = indexPath {
             tableVieww.deleteRows(at: [indexpath], with: .fade)

            }
            break
        case.update:
            if let indexpath = indexPath {

                let cell = tableVieww.cellForRow(at: indexpath) as! ItemCell
                //update cell data
                configureCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath! as NSIndexPath)
            }
            break
        case.move:

            if let indexpath = indexPath {

                tableVieww.deleteRows(at: [indexpath], with: .fade)

            }
            if let indexpath = newIndexPath {

                tableVieww.insertRows(at: [indexpath], with: .fade)
            }

        }

    }
```

here is the code section where i am adding new data its a test data yet.

```
func generateTestData() {

        let item = Items(context: context)
        item.title = "New Mac Book Pro"
        item.price = 250000
        item.details = "new Mac Book will be really good to use for Coding ha ha .. I Love iOS and Apple Devices"

        let item2 = Items(context: context)
        item2.title = "New Cassio Ediface Watch"
        item2.price = 25000
        item2.details = "I love that watch"
```

now what i am missing or doing wrong here no idea, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Find the code where you are putting new data into Core Data

Comment: Why do you create always a new FetchedResultsController on each fetch rather than the suggested lazy instantiated property? And unlike Objective-C the `break` statements and the parentheses in the `switch` expression are not needed. Finally all optional bindings in `didChange` are not needed, too. All passed index paths are 100% valid depending on the current type.

Comment: Where do you call `generateTestData()` from'?

Comment: from view did load function ...